# php validation function for name that allow UTF-8 characters plus - (minus) and space

Tags: php, validation, function, utf-8

Please help me with a function that validate an input string to allow:
1) UTF-8 characters (ex: şţăîâ) ; 2) space ; 3) minus symbol(-)

String cannot start or end with space or minus.

Thanks!

Comment: well space and minus are UTF-8 characters so by definition you just want any string that doesn't start or end with a space or minus?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use multibyte string functions

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

[UTF-8 validation in PHP without using preg_match()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282986/utf-8-validation-in-php-without-using-preg-match)