# prevent Illegal mix of collations / check for correct collation in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8, collation

my app is handling delivery addresses of people's orders in a webshop / connected marketplace like ebay.
I already accounted for UTF-8 encoding meaning it handles kyrillic, chinese etc characters correctly. However, from time to time I have entries with an unknown character � which already appears for example in the delivery address as viewed at ebay. So there's nothing going wrong along the way - the string is delivered like that.

Now at some point I am performing an address check against an official (german) address DB like so:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM adrCheck WHERE zip='".$zip."' AND street='".$street." AND city='".$city."'";
```

In case there is at least one result, I know the address must be correct.
Anyhow, when those incorrect characters appear I get a SQL error `MYSQLi Error (#1267): Illegal mix of collations (cp850_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='` which I can react to.
BUT I want to be able to check beforehand and include only those parameters into the query which are correctly encoded.

I have tried

```
print_r(mb_detect_encoding("K�ln")); // gives me UTF-8
print_r(mb_check_encoding("K�ln", "UTF-8")); // gives me 1 / true
```

and the [preg_match method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234753) which also tells me that it's valid UTF-8.

What am I overlooking? Any suggestions on how to handle this occasional snafu user input?

Comment: what charset does the database use for tables and do you set the meta charset in html? it would nice if you used prepared statements than simple `.$var.`

Comment: The DB is configured with utf8_general_ci. And I also use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my <head>. Additionally I set `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the very beginning of my index.php. And last but not least I query `SET NAMES 'utf8'` right after I initialize my connection.. Might be overkill?!

Comment: youre right about the prepared statements. Though I went with this simpler method because the inputs have been validated through several DBs before (ebay, Amazon, the shop software...) and I don't write to the DB in this instance.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error

Comment: makes no difference... I expected as much because DB collation, charset etc have all been set before. As I have mentioned, most special chars (ÄÖÜß, kyrillic, chinese...) are being handled correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurrs because you are receiving a `latin-1` encoded string (most likely, because you mentioned something about German), and try to use those as a `UTF-8` string. 
This works fine most of the time, because `latin-1` builds on top of `ASCII`, and all caracters of `ASCII` are the same in `UTF-8` (so you db does not care).

But the German `Umlaute` are encoded differently in `latin-1` and in `UTF-8`, if you try to interpret an `ä` in `latin-1` as `UTF-8` it falls back to the � symbol you've showed above.

Your test `print_r(mb_detect_encoding("K�ln"));` tells you it is `UTF-8`, because the �-symbol itself is part of UTF-8. By copying the error string it is probably copying the �-symbol rather than the invalid caracter that used to be in its place

Try to convert your input string to `UTF-8` with http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Your thought seems close, but in 99% of all my Umlaut-cases, things are correct. The specific order in front of me right now for example has invoiceAdr "Köln" (correct) and the deliveryAdr "K�ln" (incorrect).

Comment: Where do you get this data from? Is it imported from another source, or is it from your database?

Comment: Yes, comes from delivery addresses originally from ebay/Amazon/webshop orders. The cases I notice like the above show this incompatible character ALREADY for example on ebay itself when you view the order details there. I have no idea what people enter sometimes.

Comment: Oh, and I think my input string already is UTF-8. Are you saying i should just check for that character �? :)

Comment: If your string are valid UTF-8 this should work. Else you might need some additional checks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723562/how-to-detect-malformed-utf-8-string-in-php

Answer (score 0):

It seems in my case the � character is being imported into my DB as is - meaning as a valid UTF-8 character like @Florian Moser mentioned. I will go with simply checking for this character and see where it leaves me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT HEX(col)` -- what do you get?  (Spaces added for clarity.)

```
4B EFBFBD 6C 6E  -- The input had the black diamond
4B F6     6C 6E  -- you stored latin1, not utf8
4B C3B6   6C 6E  -- correctly stored utf8 (or utf8mb4)
```

You mentioned Chinese -- You really need to be using `utf8mb4`, not just `utf8`.  (`Köln` works the same in both.)

Since there are multiple cases, I recommend you study "Black Diamonds" in     [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: Yes, result was '4BEFBFBD6C6E' so this confirms that the replacement character was already part of the incoming data. Nothing I can do from my end than check for it and react accordingly. 
About chinese.. I didn't have any trouble so far (I'm working on a new version of something already running for a bunch of years) but I will look into it. Thank you for your tips.

Comment: Only some Chinese characters need 4-byte UTF-8 encodings (utf8mb4), so the Chinese you have seen so far may not have been a problem.